# Clock Work Mod Recovery isn't picking up External SD Card

Tags: external-sd, sd-card, clockworkmod-recovery

I have Clockwork Mod Recovery installed on my phone and I'm trying to install a custom ROM on it. But when I go to 'install zip from external SD card' it gives the effect as if it's going into the SD card but nothing is displayed (none of the files, folders etc that's on the card).
And when I try and go back it doesn't want to either...

Some details:

- Samsung Galaxy Note II (GT N7100)
- Clockworkmod 6
- Trying to install Paranoid Android 3.99

Thanks in advance for some advice!

Comment: What's the size and format of the SD Card?  Currently ClockworkMod recovery doesn't support exFAT partitions.  If you have a newer card that is over 32GB, chances are it's formatted using exFAT file system.  The solution is to either use a smaller card formatted as FAT32, or use a different recovery that supports exFAT, such as [TWRP](http://teamw.in/project/twrp2/115).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Chahk. I didn't try all the different SD cards and formats. Just went straight and used TWRP and that seemed to work 100%. Thanks again :)

Comment: Glad it worked for you.  I'll post this as the answer then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the size and format of your SD Card.  The current ClockworkMod recovery version (6.0.3.x) doesn't support exFAT partitions. If you have a newer card that is over 32GB, chances are it's formatted using exFAT file system, due to [limitations](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/184006) of FAT32 on Windows. The solution is to either use a smaller card formatted as FAT32, or use a different recovery that supports exFAT, such as [TWRP](http://teamw.in/project/twrp2/115), for example.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can use Philz Recovery instead. I used it with *CyanogenMod 12.1* on my *Galaxy Grand 2* (G7102). It worked perfectly and has SD Card support. You can try TWRP recovery too.